# RSA Encryption/Decryption using JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptography, rsa

I'm doing a simple program like this :

```java
package rsaexample;

import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

public class RSAExample {

    private static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE = "Public.key";
    private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "Private.key";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            System.out.println("-------Generate public and private key------");
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            System.out.println("\n-------Pulling out parameters------\n");
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec (publicKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
            RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec (privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

            System.out.println("\n---saving keys---\n");
            RSAExample rsaObj = new RSAExample ();
            rsaObj.saveKeys(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE, rsaPubKeySpec.getModulus(), rsaPubKeySpec.getPublicExponent());
            rsaObj.saveKeys(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, rsaPrivKeySpec.getModulus(), rsaPrivKeySpec.getPrivateExponent());

            byte[] encryptedData = rsaObj.encryptData ("Data to Encrypt");

            rsaObj.decryptData(encryptedData);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void savekeys (String fileName, BigInteger mod, BigInteger exp) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {

            System.out.println("Generating" + fileName + "...");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
            oos.writeObject (mod);
            oos.writeObject (exp);
            System.out.println(fileName + "generated successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (oos != null) {
                oos.close();

                if (fos != null)
                    fos.close();
            }
        }
    }
    private byte[] encryptData (String data) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("\n---ENC STARTED---");
        System.out.println("Data Before Encryption :" + data);
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = data.getBytes();
        byte[] encryptedData = null;

        try {
            PublicKey pubKey = readPublicKeyFromFile(this.PUBLIC_KEY_FILE);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
            System.out.println("Encrypted Data : " + encryptedData);

        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("---enc complete--");
        return encryptedData;
    }

    private void decryptData (byte[] data) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("\n---DEC STARTED---");
        byte[] decryptedData = null;

        try {
            PrivateKey privateKey = readPrivateKeyFromFile (this.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);
            System.out.println("DECRYPTED DATA : " + new String(decryptedData));

        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("---dec complete--");
    }
    public PrivateKey readPrivateKeyFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
            ois = new ObjectInputStream (fis);
            BigInteger modulus = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();
            BigInteger exponent = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();

            RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec (modulus, exponent);
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey privateKey = fact.generatePrivate(rsaPrivateKeySpec);
            return privateKey;
        }

        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (ois != null) {
                ois.close();

                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

But it's not working. The output should be :

[image]

Comment: It works for me, once I fix all the typos and add the missing method. Your code obviously encrypts a different string, so I don't understand why your example output doesn't have that string. You also haven't given even a smidgen of hint of clue as to why you think *...it's not working...*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new to Java and simply want to implement a Java code that encrypts and decrypts the text from file with RSA. I got this code from : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMOq4-s7Ivg . I fixed all the typos, also added the missing method, but the output is still like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO8uL.png .

Comment: You're writing "encrypts and decrypts text from file" - the above code is a simple example how to encrypt a STRING ("Data to Encrypt" (not a STRING within a file) with RSA. The encryption method is called here: "rsaObj.encryptData ("Data to Encrypt");"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your method savekeys is called savekeys with lower case, so it will get compile error where you are calling rsaObj.saveKeys.
And you are calling a method called readPublicKeyFromFile but you do not have the implementation of this method.

this should do the trick.

```
private PublicKey readPublicKeyFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
     FileInputStream fis = null;
     ObjectInputStream ois = null;

     try {
         fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
         ois = new ObjectInputStream (fis);
         BigInteger modulus = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();
         BigInteger exponent = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();

         RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec (modulus, exponent);
         KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
         PublicKey privateKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);
         return privateKey;
     }

     catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

     } finally {
         if (ois != null) {
                ois.close();
             if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
         }

     }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've changed it and also added the method you've written but output is still like that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO8uL.png .

Comment: how are you running the code.
Are you using eclipse IDE?
Try just clicking anywhere on the code and click in run as -> java application.

Comment: It looks like you are using Netbeans and instead of choosing "Java Application" you used "Java class". Maybe this video can help you with this problem (you don't need to build the complete form :-): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htdxODp534I